# WRRCSR42 Create solr cluster

Tags: solr

I followed the instructions listed in Getting started with the Retrieve and Rank service to create solr cluster, however I received the following message : WRRCSR42:The requesting service instance may not create any more free solar clusters(current limit:1)
My Questions: what this message mean? and what should I do to get the cluster id?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you've already created a Solr Cluster. IBM Watson R&R only provides one free cluster.

To retrieve the list of existing clusters, you can [use the same endpoint](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/#list_solr_clusters) as when you attempt to create the cluster, but issue a regular `GET` request instead of a `POST` request.

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters
```

[The response](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/#list_solr_clusters) lists your existing Solr clusters, and includes your `solr_cluster_id`